# How can I tell which button in a repeater got pressed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, repeater

I have the following markup in an .aspx file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ListOfAssignments" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListOfAssignments_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="AssignmentID" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="PathToFile" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="RemoveAssignment" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="RemoveAssignment_Click"/>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

There are two labels and a button in a fairly standard repeater control. The repeater is bound to a database, and populates the labels with records from the database.

Here's my problem: I have a click event for each button in the repeater. The RemoveAssignment_Click method is called when the user clicks any of the buttons. In the click event, I want to know the text of the two labels associated with whatever button the user clicked.

What I mean is, in this method:

```
protected void RemoveAssignment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code goes here
}
```

I want to be able to know the text of the labels that are adjacent to the button that was clicked. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Button.OnCommand Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This allows you to create multiple Button controls on a Web page and
>   programmatically determine which Button control is clicked.

So inside `ListOfAssignments_ItemDataBound` you'd assign the CommandArgument to the button, where the `CommandArgument` is the ID of the article to be deleted:

```
protected void ListOfAssignments_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Button delButton = e.Item.FindControl("RemoveAssignment") as Button;
        delButton.CommandArgument = //set to the value of AssignmentID
        //rest of your code
    }
}
```

And now your button should say to use your new OnCommand:

```
<asp:Button ID="RemoveAssignment" OnCommand="RemoveAssignment" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
```

And then you create the method:

```
protected void RemoveAssignment(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int articleIDToDelete = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse((string)e.CommandArgument, out articleIDToDelete))
    {
        //delete the article with an ID = articleIDToDelete
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this line: "if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)" necessary?

Comment: @LincolnBergeson In your example, it isn't necessary. But if you remove it and then later add a `HeaderTemplate` or `FooterTemplate`, the `ItemDataBound` event will fail because `e.Item.FindControl("RemoveAssignment") as Button` won't work -- because that button won't exist in the header/footer... so it is just good practice to do that all the time. It just makes sure that it is either in `AlternatingItemTemplate` or `ItemTemplate` before trying to find controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can add CommandName and CommandArgument attributes to the button tag and use them as a hint. And then in your even handler you can do e.CommandName == "xxx" or e.CommandArgument == "xxx". You can also use CommandArgument to pass the actual strings. You just need to bind the data just like you would do with a label, text, etc:

```
<asp:Button ID="RemoveAssignment" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Label1")+","+ Eval("Label2")%>' Text="Remove" OnClick="RemoveAssignment_Click"/>
```

Then in the event handler you can do something like:

```
string[] args = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] {','});
string label1 = args[0];
string label2 = args[1];
```

This should get you going.

Comment: With that hint, you'll know which label objects to read in the code behind.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson Some unique identifier, like AssignmentID.

Comment: How does it evaluate the AssignmentID? I don't understand.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson give me a minute I'll post an example

Comment: Where are you going to post it?

Answer (score -2):

Hm, I know c# and wp but you should try to set a bool and use this logic: if it is false, repeat will continue and if it is true, it'll exit the repeat. try this:

```
bool exit;


void Button_Click(eventargs stuffy here)
{
exit = true,
}

void Repeat()
{
    if (exit == false)
    {
    Repeat();
    //Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Repeat() method would get you into an infinite loop if exit were false.

Comment: Umm, yes... You are right :) You can skip frames too by adding if (framyint == 3) { //dostuff } else { framyint++; }